# Multiple same XHR in a Loop and get the response of last request.

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops, xmlhttprequest

I have a question related to promises, async-await.

Q – Let’s say we have a for loop inside which we have an XHR request, Now how do we make sure that we record the last XHR request response.

For eg.

```
let myresponse = “”;
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
fetch("http://www.mocky.io/v2/5b56dab131000062164d1f15?mocky-delay=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + "ms").then(resp => resp.json()).then(resp => {
          console.log(resp);
        });
}
```

Now in above case I want to make sure that the “myresponse” variable has the response of the last XHR request i.e when “i” was 4. Every request may have a different delay in reponse.
Let’s say
1st request has delay of 3 sec with response – “XXX”
2nd request has delay of 2 sec with response – “XXX”
3rd request has delay of 5 sec with response – “XXX”
4th request has delay of 2 sec with response – “XXX”
5th request has delay of 1 sec with response – “XXX”

so “myresponse” should contain “XXX” from the 5th Request and not the 3rd Request.

I have done it using closure and an increment variable but in that case, we have to maintain a set that preserves very requests response.

Real world example could be if a user clicks on a button 10 times we want the user to see the result of 10th Request and not the result of a request that took the longest time.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you could simply adjust the last `then()` callback.

E.g.:

```
.then(resp => { if (i === 4) { myresponse = resp; } }
```

For the more generic / button case, you could have a counter to keep track which number of requests has been issued and then have the requests callbacks check if, at the time of finishing, they are the latest request:

```
let latestId = 0;
let latestResult;
function doFetch() {
    let myId = ++latestId;
    fetch("https://example.com").then(resp => {
        if (myId === latestId) {
            latestResult = resp.json();
        }
    }
}
```